# How do I provide environmental variable with my custom Cloud Foundry buildpack?

Tags: environment-variables, cloud-foundry

I have extra simple custom sidecar buildpack. All it does in `/bin/supply` is downloading and untarring to `$DEPS_DIR/$DEPS_IDX/mylibrary` certain dependency library. Since I can have more than one sidecar buildpack I don't know `$DEPS_IDX` for mylibrary beforehand. I want to set up from within `/bin/supply` of my custom buildpack environment variable `export MYLIBRARY_PATH=$DEPS_DIR/$DEPS_IDX/mylibrary` so main application could use it. How do I do that? Where do I put that export?

I know that I can put that variable to `manifest.yml` or set up it with `cf set-env` but that's fragile and I want to set up env var close to place where I supply related dependency. I saw that some custom buildpacks write custom scripts to `$DEPS_DIR/$DEPS_IDX/profile.d`. I tried that but those scripts are never executed. Should I try to reach `/etc/profile.d` from `/bin/supply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put script exporting that value to `${BUILD_DIR}/.profile.d/` directory (it's where app located at build). All scripts from there are moved to `/etc/profile.d` and sourced at buildpack launch. BUILD_DIR should be visible during `/bin/supply`